# Intercept TabSelected if condition is not valid - Android TabLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I am trying to intercept `TabSelected` `EventHandler` in the `TabLayout`, to display a Dialog if some data is not saved.
If the user clicks "*yes*", the **new** tab selected is displayed. If not, the **old** tab is displayed (stays the same).

How can I display the previous Tab (if the condition is not valid)?:

**MyActivity.cs**

```
private int previousTabPosition =-1;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

...
OnCreate(){
tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabbar);
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(pager);
tabLayout.TabSelected += TabLayout_TabSelected;
...
}
private void TabLayout_TabSelected(object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedTab = e.Tab.Position;
    }
```

**My FragmentAdapter:**

```
public class MFragmentAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private const int BasePagesCount = 7;

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Context context;
    private ItemViewModel Vm;
    private bool canSelect;
    private int pagesCount = BasePagesCount;
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;

    public InterventionFragmentAdapter(ItemViewModel Vm, bool canSelect, Context context, FragmentManager fm, CustomViewPager viewPager) : base(fm)
    {
        this.fragmentManager = fm;
        this.context = context;
        this.Vm = Vm;
        this.canSelect = canSelect;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        if (Vm.Troubleshooting())
        {
            pagesCount--;
        }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return pagesCount; }
    }

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 1:
                return FirstFragment.GetInstance(this.Vm);
            case 2:

                return SecondFragment.GetInstance(this.Vm);
            case 3:
               ....
            default:
                return DefaultFragment.GetInstance(this.Vm, this.canSelect);
        }
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new String(context.GetString(Resource.String.first_tab));
            case 1:
                return new String(context.GetString(Resource.second_tab));
            ....
            default:
                return new String("-");
        }
    }

    public void UpdateFragments(ItemViewModel Vm)
    {
        this.Vm = Vm;
        foreach (Fragment fragment in fragmentManager.Fragments)
        {
            if (fragment is IChangeListener)
            {
                (fragment as IChangeListener).OnObjectChanged(Vm);
            }
        }
    }


    public int GetFirstPageIndex()
    {
        if (pagesCount == BasePagesCount)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }


    public int GetSecondPageIndex()
    {
        if (pagesCount == BasePagesCount)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        return -1;
    }
...
    }
```

**MyActivity.axml**:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabContentStart="30dp"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <Project.Views.Droid.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use **tabLayout.TabSelected** event and intercept the **tabLayout.Clicked** event

create a **SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter** :

```
  public class SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {

        private static string[] mTitles = { "tab1", "tab2", "tab3" };
        private TablayoutActivity tablayoutActivity;

        public SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, TablayoutActivity tablayoutActivity) : base(fm)
        {
            this.tablayoutActivity = tablayoutActivity;
        }

        public override int Count => mTitles.Length;

        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        //custom Tab's style
        public View GetTabView(int position)
        {
            View tabView = LayoutInflater.From(tablayoutActivity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.tabitem, null);
            TextView textView = tabView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
            textView.Text = mTitles[position];
            return tabView;
        }
    }
```

then in **OnCreate** method :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.tablayout);
        // Create your application here
        pagerAdapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabs);
        pagerAdapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, this);
        viewPager.Adapter=pagerAdapter;
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        //Set the tablayout.Tab's style and intercept the tabLayout.Clicked event by use "tabView.SetOnTouchListener"
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null)
            {
                tab.SetCustomView(pagerAdapter.GetTabView(i));
                if (tab.CustomView != null)
                {
                    View tabView = (View)tab.CustomView.Parent;
                    tabView.Tag=i;
                    tabView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

finally,in the **OnTouch** method:

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
       if(e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) { 
        int pos = (int)v.Tag;
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .SetTitle("notice")
                .SetMessage("Have you saved data?")
                //if no will stay current tab
                .SetNegativeButton("No", delegate
                {
                    return;
                })
                //if yes will display new tab
                .SetPositiveButton("Yes", delegate
                {
                    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(pos);
                    if (tab != null)
                    {
                        tab.Select();
                    }
                })

                .Create();

        alertDialog.Show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hey @Leo Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand the use of SetCustomView(() and GetTabView() here. My FragmentAdapter is a 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' where i only used GetItem()

Comment: and what is the TabLayoutActivity? The parent activity you mean?

Comment: yes，it means parent activity（the context），and setCustomView and GetTabVie are used to get the tabview for each Tab that could setToutchListener，and they also could set the style of Tab（e.g. you want the Tab within icon and text or others）

Comment: I tried using the OnTouch() before and it didn't work. it, sometimes fires the pop up multiple times because detecting the down movement is quite tricky. That's why i wanted to use TabSelected instead.

Comment: you should return true to intercept the event then do select by tab.Select （ps：listen the down or up action）

Comment: you could have a try use the method above，i test that work fine

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that! I don't have a tabitem layout for my tabs. each tab has its own layout

Comment: `Resource.Layout.tabitem` just the layout in my sample,you should Instead of yours which as you say each tab has its own layout

Comment: i see,your Tab is only a text ? if yes ,you could write a tabItem layout which only contain a TextView like my sample code in GetTabView

Comment: no its not only a text. its a complex layout (lists, custom views, etc) and very different from tab to tab.

Comment: for example，you have three tabs，and the tab only show "Tab1"，"Tab2"，"Tab3"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189687/discussion-between-hanaa-and-leo-zhu-msft).